# React component which is bound to array doesn't re-renders itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a simple React component which bound to array "items". Now in the  update the underlying state by clicking on the "Add Item" button. The state is getting updated, but somehow React is not re-rendering it self. Can any one help?

```
interface IComponentState {
  items: any[];
}

class UpdateArrayDemo extends React.Component<{}, IComponentState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: new Array()
    };

    this.onAddItem = this.onAddItem.bind(this);
  }

  adding some state here
  onAddItem() {
    const items = this.state.items;

    //add one item
    let item = Date();
    items.push(item)

    this.setState({
      items : items
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.items);
    });
  }

  render() : JSX.Element {
    return(
      <div>
     <button onClick={this.onAddItem}>Add Items</button>
         <ul>
           {
             (this.state != null && this.state.items != null) ? 
              this.state.items.map((data : any) => {
                <li>{data}</li>
              }) 
             : ''
             }
           </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }  
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <UpdateArrayDemo />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);



//refer link on code pen
//https://codepen.io/yoghcl/pen/BroGYO?editors=0010
```

Comment: Your map function isn't returning anything. Either remove the curly braces around `<li>` or add `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Please change

```
this.state.items.map((data : any) => {
                <li>{data}</li>
              })
```

to

```
this.state.items.map((data : any) => <li>{data}</li>)
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. I am curious to know what was the issue.